# ActiveXobject in javascript not working in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, activexobject

Working in a .NET project where we have layering done with Database-> XSL-> Presentation Layer.

There is issue of ACTIVEXOBJECT not being read in IE11, which further creates a Doucment object to read the XSL.
I have tried different ways to handle the same in Javascript, but none has worked.
The above function is written in initForm() , called in Javascript, which creates oDoc as an object of ActiveXObject, which further reads the XSL defined for the same and manipulation to display the page. It works fine in IE10, IE11 ( if run in compatibility mode), but when run without compatibility mode, oDoc is NULL.

```
oDoc = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument");
```

Above is the original statement fetched from Javascript of the Page. 
I tried using 
• different arguments mentioned above, but none worked. Either it throw `ERROR` as oDoc is `NULL` or `initForm()` is undefined.
• Different method to fetch the XSL, but faced issue as it has XSLT and XML pages to be fetched which is not present in current functionality.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use that check for IE11: [Mircosoft - IE11](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn423948%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Starting with IE11, the navigator object supports plugins and mimeTypes properties. In addition, the window.ActiveXObject property is hidden from the DOM. (This means you can no longer use the property to detect IE11.)